# What is this snail? (Location: Bangkok, Thailan; size: 3 cm long, 5 mm wide; color: mostly black)

Tags: species-identification, zoology, molluscs, snail, gastropod

What is this snail? (Location: Bangkok, Thailan; size: 3 cm long, 5 mm wide; color: mostly black)

[image]

Video:  https://youtu.be/vxig5QOSoss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly [*Macrochlamys indica*](https://inpn.mnhn.fr/photos/uploads/webtofs/inpn/ant/91430.jpg) or another species in the same genus, based on shell morphology.

[image: Macrochlamys indica]

[Source](https://inpn.mnhn.fr/espece/cd_nom/433310?lg=en)

Comment: Thanks, looks similar indeed!